# Why won't Microsoft EDGE show EPUB ebooks?

Tags: epub, windows

I have been using the Microsoft EDGE web browser to read EPUB ebooks (my favored format, since they're smaller than the equivalent MOBI/AZW3 or PDF ebook file).

However, EDGE now won't show the content once loaded.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but Microsoft declared [EDGE will no longer be able to show EPUB files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4517840/microsoft-edge-download-an-epub-app-to-keep-reading), so when they get the [KB4522355](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4522355/windows-10-update-kb4522355) patch into your system to kill that ability, it's gone forever.

As Microsoft stated, other EPUB reader apps are available, including the Open Source [fbReader for Windows](https://fbreader.org/win32), as well as 12 others in the Microsoft Store.